# Reading eeprom from external medical device using arduino

Tags: parsing, arduino, spi, medical, eeprom

I bought a blood pressure module off ebay and want to interface it with an arduino mega and store data to a database. So far I have got the database setup which it stores hard coded values and ready to retrieve values from the blood pressure modules eeprom, I have soldered wires to the modules eeprom's SCL SDA and WP.

So far I have written code to reads values from the the eeprom on the module but to me its more or less jiberish because the values I am printing out are the raw values that the eeprom produces which are lines of numbers which vary from 0-9. Below is an snippet of the values I am printing but not all of it though:

```
823248 9856325553 10 873248 5556325653 10 823249 5556324850 10 823248 54553255102 10 
823248 5349325497 10 823248 5348325748 10 873248 5356325748 10
```

(Values printed aren't spaced, I spaced them myself because there is alot of values repeated and is easier to read)

As you can see a lot of these values repeat and so I am assuming that the values between the spaces that change might be the values that I might want, but im new to using eeprom so I am not 100% sure.

Help in how I should interpret/parse these values or even a push in the right direction if I am going by it in the wrong way would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: no code, no help, my oracle ball is broken

Comment: What is the CHIP part number of the EEPROM? That will provide a datasheet and the protocol it speaks. Allowing one to decode the stream